# The CSS for this Nav worked offline but isn't working online

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found css code for a navigation that I really liked, for a site which I am doing for a friend of mine, (this menu:http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/19/blur-menu-with-css3-transitions/). For some reason, although it worked perfectly fine offline, once i uploaded it, the menu failed to work on the web server. If anyone has any inclinations of how to fixe this, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks

The code is here:
www.simmonsmultimedia.com/doc/main.html

Answer (score 2):

it seems your CSS folder is capitalized on the server, and assuming its a linux host, makes everything case sensitive

i'm assuming this because:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" /> <---- DOESNT WORK
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css" /> <---- DOESNT WORK
    <link href="CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <---- WORKS
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing CSS 404 not found. From the chrome debugger console:

http://www.simmonsmultimedia.com/doc/css/demo.css
http://www.simmonsmultimedia.com/doc/css/style2.css

These files don't seem to exist

Comment: Thank you! That coupled with the first answer worked. It is because it was searching for it sensitive to the case.